# spinner.onItemSelectedListener causes crash on rotation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, rotation, spinner

I have a `spinner` inside a `fragment`. Setting `onItemSelectedListener` in `onViewCreated` causes a crash after device rotation.

This is my code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    myspinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            Log.d("debug", "onSelectItem")
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    }

    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayOf(getString(R.string.mystring), getString(R.string.mystring1), getString(R.string.mystring2)))
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    myspinner.adapter = adapter
    myspinner.setSelection(Values.selectedIndex)
}
```

I receive the following `errors`:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: myproject, PID: 12899
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter view
                      at myproject.MyFragment$onViewCreated$1.onItemSelected(Unknown Source:45)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:922)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1105)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:1081)
                      at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:191)
                      at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:602)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:420)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1212)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1552)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1212)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1552)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1450)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:516)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1632)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:809)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2719)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1572)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1856)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7184)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

If I comment out `onItemSelectedListener` then it doesn't crash.

Comment: may be this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255559/kotlin-crashes-on-android-when-selected-item-view-is-null

Comment: @secretpaladin That fixed it. I literally just had to add a `?` after the second parameter `view: View` in `onItemSelected`.